# how I can see view points in Autodeskforge

Tags: api, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

We have been working on the web based application using **AudeskForge**, where we are uploading the file (*.rvt,.NWD*) files but we can track the **ViewPoint** in it. On other hand we can see the ViewPoint when we open files in respective applications (Revit, Navizwork).

We have been using audesk-model-derivatives to get the data.

**I would like to how I can see view points in forge?**

PS:So idea is to get possibly all data and datapoints from the stand-alone software to webbased forge app.

Comment: With my knowledge, unfortunately, Forge has not supported Navisworks Viewpoint. While it is feasible to use Navisworks API to dump the viewpoint data and with Forge Viewer API, produce the corresponding View State, or drive camera. will this workaround be fine to you at this moment?

Comment: We have created plugin which send the JSON Plugin to my application precisely in database, while on other hand we are uloading NWD to on Forge.mydomain.com ..and now they are navigating it..but like to remove this JSON plugin

Comment: Hi @SandyUgale, sorry for the late response. Finally we logged a wish to ask Forge services to translate viewpoints of Navisworks to the final dataset. The wish ID is DERI-4423. your patience and understanding are appreciated.

Comment: Hi @XiaodongLiang! Has this been implemented yet? how can I track the request (DERI-4423)? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Naoric I did not see an update with this ticket. Sorry for this. I will check with related team if there is any news.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Model Derivative API has translated the data of saved viewpoints now, and Forge Viewer provides the APIs to get those presets cameras. They are stored at:

```
  presets_cams = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().cameras
```

Then, you can switch current view to that of the predefined saved viewpoint:

```
  NOP_VIEWER.impl.setViewFromCamera(presets_cams[index]);
```

Comment: Q.1) Is it possible to navigate viewpoints on Forge in NWD, please confirm this? Same as the way Im navigating clashesh..

Q.2)I have imported probably all available date with viewpoint on cloud so I want to user just click on VP and it will navigate to respective model on forge.. is it possible? If yes then what data I need to get from naviswork to impement it.

Q3.)Which is the best information we can give to user so he can easily search and locate the viewpoint in Naviswork and also in Revit to solve it..my guess is ElementID..confirm once!

Comment: @SandyUgale,  1) do you mean by navigating Navisworks viewpoints in Forge? I think my answer has replied it can. As to ClashTest, you will need to dump yourself, this is a blog I wrote: https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/10/clash-detective-from-navisworks-to-forge-viewer.html  2) sure it can, but as said, Forge can translate the saved viewpoints of Navisworks now, what you need is just to follow my code above to switch the viewpoint.  3) sorry I do not understand the question. I'd suggest you post a new SO and describe with some information such as snapshpts