# Hox to load viewpoint datas with the API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have an export in `xml` of a viewpoint from a Navisworks file. I've find nothing about how to load it in my web viewer with the API.

I've found this SO but it do not help me a lot : 
[how I can see view points in Autodeskforge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44380480/how-i-can-see-view-points-in-autodeskforge)

How can I do it?

Comment: I checked that wish DERI-4423, it is still Open. Sorry for this. you would have to parse the xml of saved viewpoints, and translate them to produce the corresponding View State, or drive camera by Forge Viewer API. I have not an existing code, but I have written a blog on how to push clash test to Forge Viewer, and translate viewpoint of clash to the viewer. probably it could help a bit: https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/10/clash-detective-from-navisworks-to-forge-viewer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got Model Derivative API has translated the data of saved viewpoints now, and Forge Viewer provides the APIs to get those presets cameras. They are stored at:

```
  presets_cams = NOP_VIEWER.model.getData().cameras
```

Then, you can switch current view to that of the predefined saved viewpoint:

```
  NOP_VIEWER.impl.setViewFromCamera(presets_cams[index]);
```